# Can I connect The Serval Mesh (Android) to B.A.T.M.A.N (Ubuntu)?

Tags: networking, android, mesh

According to B.A.T.M.A.N. [site](http://www.open-mesh.org/projects/open-mesh/wiki/Experience), The Serval Mesh is based on B.A.T.M.A.N. project, if it is true, can I connect my Android device to my Laptop? and how? thank you.

Regards,
Esminetsz

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. While the Serval Project lies on top of the BATMAN protocol, it implements many features (such routing to phone numbers, etc) not in the BATMAN protocol.

Also, the Serval Project is considering eventually moving away from the BATMAN protocol and using solely RFC922.